# Select values which contains specific characters even if it's not in the same order

Tags: mysql

My problem is that I want an SQL Query that will allow me to select values which contains specific characters even if it's not in the same order.
This is my list:
https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/729697contacts1.png

I want to show only values that contain the characters rachid even if it's not in order, or the word contain some other characters in it, this is what I should obtain:

https://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/706919contacts2.png

Thanks

Comment: have you got table structures? example data? expected results? attempted queries?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon I have edited my question, you can see the picture of my list

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM [table_name]
 WHERE name <> 'hahaha' and name <> 'hhhhhh'
```

This would display all of your records and hide 'hahaha' and 'hhhhhh'

UPDATE:

```
SELECT *
 FROM [table_name]
 WHERE name LIKE '%rachid%' OR
 WHERE name LIKE '%rach id%' OR
 WHERE name LIKE '%rach'id%' OR
 WHERE name LIKE '%rach ide%'
```

This would give you any row where rachid matches at any point in the name field.
You would have to keep adding like statements to cover other options.

I think you're also talking about distinct values so for that you would need -

SELECT DISTINCT.....

Comment: @RachidAzzanati you want to remove all values with rachid?

Comment: Thank you, but I want to show all rows that contain the characters rachid even if it's not in order, or even if the word is between other words on in link with other words. Is that clear sir?

Comment: @RachidAzzanati see update, i think thats what you want

Comment: Thank you sir, it's a little closer to what I want, but I want also to show values "rach id" and "rach'id" and "rach ide", and sort all my list for every single word and remove only differences. I'm sorry for my english, If it's not clear, I will re-explain.

Comment: the problem with DISTINCT it that It will show only one of all rachid, all I want is to show all values that contain the same characters even if the order is not the same, and not show the other values that don't have duplicates. Thank you sir for your time and your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want fuzzy logic. MySql doesn't support such thing out of the box. I found "Levenshtein distance" in this context. You should read about it.

You could generate a search value list from outside the sql.
Little php example:

```
function getLevenshtein1($word)
{
    $words = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++) {
        // insertions
        $words[] = substr($word, 0, $i) . '_' . substr($word, $i);
        // deletions
        $words[] = substr($word, 0, $i) . substr($word, $i + 1);
        // substitutions
        $words[] = substr($word, 0, $i) . '_' . substr($word, $i + 1);
    }
    // last insertion
    $words[] = $word . '_';
    return $words;
}
```

https://gordonlesti.com/fuzzy-fulltext-search-with-mysql/

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, let me explain you:  this is my controller function to remode duplicated data from contacts table.  public function removeDuplicate() {

  $results = Contact::whereIn('name', function ($query) {
   $query->select('name')->from('contacts')->groupBy('name')->havingRaw('count(*) > 1');
  })->distinct()->get();

  foreach ($results as $rs) {
   $rs->delete();
  }

  return back();

 }. do you have an Idea on how can I use this Levenshtein function to let rachid = _rachid then delete them? Thank you